# Render computed HTML in RMarkdown

Tags: html, r, r-markdown, pandoc

I have a function that produces some html and I want RMarkdown to render the html.

````
```{r}
outputFromAFunction <- '<span style="background-color: #A6CEE3">A</span>'
outputFromAFunction
```
````

How do I tell rmarkdown to render `outputFromAFunction` as the colored letter A instead of simply printing the html as text.

I have already tried the `results='asis'` code chunk option and it removes the closing span tag and does not render the html.

I need to render a html page not shiny.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `results='asis'` and `cat` the value:

````
```{r results='asis'}
outputFromAFunction <- '<span style="background-color: #A6CEE3">A</span>'
cat(outputFromAFunction)
```
````

Comment: Thank you so much Kent!